# magento 2 how to redirect target path url?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

how to redirect target path url?

target path =  http://www.test.com/catalog/product/view/id/1016/category/729

redirect to

orignal path =  http://www.test.com/product-url.html

i need to fix for all products.

Is there any solution to fix this problem with code.

Comment: I have faced this error and I using this module: https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

Comment: https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites the module only using for the regenerate url

Answer (score 0):

> Regenerate Url rewrites

1. https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites
2. https://github.com/elgentos/regenerate-catalog-urls
3. https://shreejiinfosys.co.in/url-rewrite-generator-magento-2.html

> Create URL Rewrites in Magento 2

1. https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/magento-2-url-rewrite.html
2. https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-create-url-rewrites-magento-2.html

Comment: i am looking something redirect target path to original path like above example i have given

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem in Magento 2.4.3

**How to reproduce:**

1. Calling domain.tld/catalog/category/view/id/3
2. Calling domain.tld/some-friendly-url.html

**Expected result:**
/catalog/category/view/id/3 should redirect to /some-friendly-url.html

**Actual result:**
Both URLs are accessible and there is no redirection to friendly URL